# Pass unreaded items from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wanna pass to my "View" if there's any unreaded interaction within a call.

It's like an e-mail, If you have an unread email within a group of emails, it will be bold displayed. I'm doing something like that.

I have a Repository, so I'm doing this...

```
foreach(item in callRepo.All())
{
    if (item.Interactions.Count(x=>x.Unread==true)>0) 
    {
    }
}
return View(callRepo.All());
```

A call has many Interactions, and I wanna pass to my View if there is any unread Interaction.

---

This is how it's working on my View now:

var CSSclass="Readed"

```
foreach(item in callRepo.All())
{
  if (item.Interactions.Count(x=>x.Unread==true)>0){CSSclass="Unreaded"}
  <tr class=@CSSclass>}
```

---

I do not want to treat this business on my View.

Is there a way to do that on my controller?

.

Is my question clear? Sorry about the bad english.Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many time are you going to call this repository method (I've counted 3 so far)?

I would recommend you to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Interaction> Interactions { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var items = callRepo.All();
    var model = items.Select(item => new MyViewModel
    {
        Interactions = item.Interactions,
        IsRead = item.Interactions.Any(x => x.Unread == true)
    });
    return View(model);
}
```

and your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</table>
```

and in the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    var css = model.IsRead ? "read" : "unread";
}
<tr class="@css">
    ...
</tr>
```

A further improvement of this code would be to replace the `IEnumerable<Interaction>`  property in the view model by a specific `IEnumerable<InteractionViewModel>` and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to externalize the mapping between the model and the view model.